# What are the preferred server resources needed to run a magento 2 ecommerce site? php memory limit, virtual and physical memory? ,

Tags: magento2, php, memory

When updating magento to 2.3, warning was given to set php memory to a minimum of 2048. Wondering what the preferred settings/resources are and if hosting on a shared server is fine.

Comment: You're using a shared server?   I would strongly consider literally any other cart, and if no other choice can work, only then magento.  Seriously, I wish it was made more clear, though I likely had no choice anyway... you still might.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It's just that I'm familiar with it but am running into many issues with magento 2. What would you suggest?

Comment: All of the platforms choices are thoroughly horrible, but I'd suggest woocommerce.  shopify or bicommerce if SAAS is OK, but you'll be working around either as often as you're working within them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the needed php configuration.

```
memory_limit = 2G
max_input_vars = 10000
max_input_time = 1800
max_execution_time = 3600
always_populate_raw_post_data = -1
```

According to technology stack requirements:

**Memory requirement:**
Upgrading the Magento applications and extensions you obtain from Magento Marketplaces and other sources can require up to 2GB of RAM. If you are using a system with less than 2GB of RAM, we recommend you create a swap file; otherwise, your upgrade might fail.

References:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Required PHP settings doc:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/php-settings.html

PHP settings errors doc:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_php-set.html

Your server is shared or dedicated must support above settings for upgrade or install it or any modules of it.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. The only option I don't see in my php ini settings is the raw_post_data.